# Yarn RM Tracking URL: ApplicationMaster & History

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

If running applications, I can go to spark history via the link in YARN -> Tracking URL: ApplicationMaster

[image]

If the application has terminated, the link will not be to ApplicationMaster, but to History.
But there is no transition to this link

[image]

How can I configure it so that even for completed applications I can go to the history?
:180/history/application_1626707205951_7475

this parameter is configured in the config - yarn.log.server.url -

these three Spark configuration properties conf

1. spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://SPH-HOST:18088
2. spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://NN:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory
3. spark.eventLog.enabled=true